# Am I right about LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecma262

I read a lot of articles, I was very confused, I also read the [ES6 official documentation](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-lexical-environments).
When creating an execution context, LE and VE initially point to the same Lexical Environment. But then the document says `let and const declarations define variables that are scoped to the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment`.

Since it's the same, Do they refer to lexical environments that have both let-defined and var-defined variables? Or do we create a new lexical environment when we encounter `let/const`, and then have LE point to this new lexical environment, as I have shown below?
here is the code

```
0:  function do_something() {
1:     var a = 1;
2:     let b = 2;
3:     while (true) {
4:         var c = 3;
5:         let d = 4;
6:         console.log(b);
7:         break;
8:     }
9:  }
10:
11: do_something();
```

When executing a function, create the execution context as follows,with LE and VE pointing to the same lexical environment

```
ExecutionContext:
    LexicalEnvironment:
        a -> undefined, c -> undefined
        outer: global
    VariableEnvironment:
        a -> undefined, c -> undefined
        outer: global
    ...
```

But there is let/const, so a new lexical environment is created and LE points to the newly created lexical environment.

```
ExecutionContext:
    LexicalEnvironment:
        b -> uninitialized
        outer: VariableEnvironment //here should VariableEnvironment,也就是当前执行上下文的词法环境
    VariableEnvironment:
        a -> undefined, c -> undefined
        outer: global
    ...
```

When you encounter `while`, you need to create a new block-level scope that is, a new lexical environment

```
ExecutionContext:
    LexicalEnvironment:
        d -> uninitialized
        outer:
            LexicalEnvironment
                b -> 2
                outer: VariableEnvironment
    VariableEnvironment:
        a -> 1, c -> undefined
        outer: global
    ...
```

and When we leave the while block we restore the original lexical environment.

```
ExecutionContext:
    LexicalEnvironment:
        b -> nothing
        outer: VariableEnvironment //here should VariableEnvironment,也就是当前执行上下文的词法环境
    VariableEnvironment:
        a -> undefined, c -> undefined
        outer: global
    ...
```

Following this model, I feel that variable lookup can be done normally, but I don't know it's right or not.
I read a lot of articles that separate LE and VE, but the documentation says that they start with the same value, which makes me very confused

I looked at the official ES6 documentation, as well as many other articles.

Ah, I found that this seems to be unable to explain the situation of encountering closures.

Answer (score 1):

> Since it's the same, do they refer to lexical environments that have both let-defined and var-defined variables?

Yes. The rules for initialising the environment guarantee that there are no naming conflicts between lexical and var-scoped variables, i.e. it does not need to distinguish between them by putting them in different environments but it just throws an exception when encountering a `let` (or `const`, `class` etc) and a `var` (or `function`) declaration with the same name.

> Or do we create a new lexical environment when we encounter let/const?

No. The environments are created and initialised with the declared variables when the new scope is entered, typically when calling a function or entering a block.

So why is this *VariableEnvironment* component of the execution needed at all, you might wonder? Actually, its only use is an edge case: direct `eval` calls in sloppy mode. They can introduce `var`iable and `function` declarations in an existing environment record, namely the *VariableEnvironment* of the current execution context in which the `eval()` call was made.

Comment: Amazing, the original lexical environment has all the let/const-defined var-defined property values? Will the Lexical Environment Components and Variable Environment Components be distinguished later?Or How to understand the sentence `let and const declarations define variables that are scoped to the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment` in the official document

Comment: They are distinguished insofar as that the LexicalEnvironment changes when a block scope is entered but the VariableEnvironment doesn't. The key in the note you read is "*The variables are created when their containing Environment Record is instantiated*", and are found via [static scope analysis](https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/#sec-syntax-directed-operations-scope-analysis).